# How to embed HtmlUnit web client at JEditorPane?

Tags: java, htmlunit, jeditorpane

I know that JEditorPane does not render web elements well. Therefore I tried HtmlUnit. However, I wish to embed the JS supported browser into JEditorPane to see the results, and the .setPage() of JEditorPane does not take in a HTML page but a URL. Am on a Javax application. How may I fix this?

On a side note, I will need to embed visual data onto the browser later on, via D3. Appreciate all advice given.

Here is my code snippet:

```
    webclient = new WebClient (BrowserVersion.CHROME);  
    currentpage = (HtmlPage) webclient.getPage("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    currentpage.executeJavaScript("document.write('Hello World!');");

    jepuser = new JEditorPane();
    jepuser.setEditable(false);

    try{
        jepuser.setPage(currentpage);           //<---
        jepuser.setContentType("text/html");
        jepuser.updateUI();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    spuser = new JScrollPane(jepuser);
    spuser.setViewportBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
    spuser.setSize(800, 420);
    spuser.setLocation(280, 140);
    spuser.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    //spuser.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    spuser.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    add(spuser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JEditorPane can render some basic HTML (probably of version 3.2 or so)
HtmlUnit is a headless browser used mainly for unit testing

It seems that you want to embed a fully functional browser into your Java application. I would recomend trying JavaFX - it has a native browser control based on WebKit - [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html)

Comment: thank you. but how may I continue to make the above prog run in any way?